# how to use kubernates with IBM bluemix containers

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, bluemix

I am newbie in Kubernetes. I didn't find option for IBM Bluemix container in your_provider for cloud configuration. (I am referring to this [Kubernetes Getting Started Guide](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/).) Cloud you please tell me, Is it possible to integrate Bluemix with Kubernetes or not, If so,what can be a good starting point?

Comment: IBM bluemix offers IBM containers, which is a different service than Kubernetes that is offered on Google Container Engine. What exactly is the option that you didn't find on GKE? Is it possible to provide more details on what you are looking for so we can be able to help you. More information about Google Container Engine is available in this Help Center article: https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/

Comment: Since March/2017 Kubernetes is available on IBM Cloud Containers service, as informed below: https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/03/kubernetes-now-available-ibm-bluemix-container-service/ You can get more details at the following documentation link too: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_versions.html#cs_versions

Answer (score 1):

As confirmed in this [other disccussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112160/how-to-use-kubernetes-with-ibm-bluemix-containers) "Today it is not feasible to run Kubernetes natively within the Bluemix platform". Some updates might be posted there.